# How to show Google font preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading Google font-families name into a select-list. When user select any font-family from the list, then I load that font dynamically. My code:

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=...", {}, function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
        $('#fc').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.family)
                .text(value.family));
    });
    $('#fc').selectmenu({ select: function () {
        $('body').append("<link rel='stylesheet' id='colorbox-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + escape($(this).selectmenu("value")) + "' type='text/css' media='all' />");
    }
    });
});
```

Now I want to show the preview of the font to the user before loading that font.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the fonts into your page as [described here](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader). Then simply have a div with your sample text and style it based on the font chosen from the drop-down.

Specifically look at the last section on adding event handlers - you can use JS to detect when font(s) have finished loading and apply them as appropriate

Comment: Thanks, But according to this way, each time when user select the font, the font will loads and if after seen the preview user don`t want to use that font than that means we unnecessarily loaded that font. Is`tn this a costly approach ?

Comment: The bottom line is that you can't show a font without loading it - And it will only be loaded for the duration of the page lifetime. Once the user has picked a font, you just store the one they chose and will only load that one in future when re-displaying the content. The only alternatives would be to a) load the font on a server somewhere, render an image with it, then send that image to the user. The load still happens but not for the user. b) pre-render images representing all possible fonts. This would be a pain to maintain as new ones are added but faster when used than option a

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this challenge myself, so used some console action and open sourced the following: https://github.com/onassar/GoogleWebFonts-FontFamilyPreviewImages

I'll be pretty active in maintaining it (just gotta write up the docs now).

Comment: Just came to a similar conclusion for a web app I'm building, never would have thought someone already did all the work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This github project comes to mind. It too offers the user a preview of google fonts [Fontselect jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this problem myself recently when adding Google Fonts API functionality to have a constantly updated select list of currently available Google fonts. I used the [jQuery Fontselect Plugin](https://github.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin) as a base but I modified it quite a bit to fit my purpose.
I explain how I tackled it here: https://www.bibleget.io/2020/04/released-v5-3-of-the-wordpress-plugin/
Basically I'm using some sophisticated cURL requests to the Google Fonts API in order to download locally a reduced version of each font with only the characters that are used for the name of the font, and then preloading those reduced versions of the fonts onto the page that will have the select dropdown.
You can see it in action here: https://youtu.be/zqJqU_5UZ5M