# Font Selection Combo Box using google fonts

Tags: html, google-fonts

I want to make a font selection combo box (html 'select' element) where different fonts are displayed in each row of the popup window of the combo box. It works fine when I style the rows (option tags) with the fonts only in the case the font is installed on the client's operating system.
For some reason it seems like the google font is not taken from my google font link.
E.g.

Has someone an idea how I can use the google font from the link in the rows?

This is my select code:

```js
function onFontSelectChange(font) {
  document.getElementById("fontSelect").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Splash&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sedgwick+Ave&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julee&family=Amatic+SC&&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Handlee&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<select id="fontSelect" class="form-select art_font_inkfree" name="param_Font" onchange="onFontSelectChange (this)">
  <option value="Julee" selected style="font-family:Julee">
    Julee
  </option>
  <option value="Amatic SC" style="font-family:Amatic">
    Amatic SC
  </option>
  <option value="Courgette" style="font-family:Courgette">
    Courgette
  </option>
  <option value="Handlee" style="font-family:Handlee">
    Handlee
  </option>
</select>
```

In the image below you can see that some fonts are applied and some not. The Fonts which are applied are installed on my operating system: Drop Down Box

[image]

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Styling the rows is not working when font is not installed on the client's operating system.

Comment: Please provide some of your codes as well as the image of the final result for easy debbuging.

Comment: Loading each font on the page might be too heavy if you want to show more than a few fonts. Here's a project that has a png version for every Google font: https://github.com/getstencil/GoogleWebFonts-FontFamilyPreviewImages. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577379/how-to-show-google-font-preview.

Comment: I posted a code snippet. It is only about a few fonts. For some reason its not working in the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google fonts developer api to get the list of all font family and theie variants

by using this link with your developer apikey

https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY

you can refer the following link for more

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't know how to use google fonts. The fonts are working fine in all other html elements. The only place where they are not working is inside the popup of the combo box (i.e. in the html option tag inside the select tag).

Comment: Can you give your code for the select, that would be helpful to find the solution

Comment: I have added a code snippet where you can see the behavior

Answer (score 0):

hey i have updated your code try this and if you want anything more please let me know

```js
function onFontSelectChange(font) {
  document.getElementById("fontSelect").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Splash&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sedgwick+Ave&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julee&family=Amatic+SC&&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Handlee&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<select id="fontSelect" class="form-select art_font_inkfree" name="param_Font" onchange="onFontSelectChange (this)">
  <option selected>Select from the list</option>
  <option value="Julee" style="font-family:Julee">
    Julee
  </option>
  <option value="Amatic SC" style="font-family: Amatic SC;">
    Amatic SC
  </option>
  <option value="Courgette" style="font-family:Courgette">
    Courgette
  </option>
  <option value="Handlee" style="font-family:Handlee">
    Handlee
  </option>
</select>
```